# How to eliminate duplicate values in a row

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains customer id number, and all email addresses we've collected for said customer.  There is one row per customer, and close to 10,000 rows.  In most cases, there are multiple occurrences of the same email address.  I would like to consolidate the list of addresses per customer down to a unique list.  I find many helpful articles on how to get unique values from data that occurs in separate rows, but this task needs to get unique values from separate columns.

I want to take this....

```
CustomerID | Email1              | Email2            | Email3            | Email4            | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345      | myemail@example.com | example@gmail.com | example@gmail.com | myemail@example.com
```

and turn it into this...

```
CustomerID | Email1              | Email2            | Email3            | Email4            | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345      | myemail@example.com | example@gmail.com |                   |                   |
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel???

Comment: In excel VBA would be easier ..

Answer (score 0):

As a one-off exercise, you could select all of your data, copy and paste it to a new sheet using the 'Transpose' option (to put the rows into columns).  Use Excel's "Remove Duplicates" option on the Data ribbon to delete the duplicate rows.  After the duplicates are removed, copy and paste with transpose back to your first sheet.